# Do uncomputable functions exist that are of the order of a computable function?

Tags: complexity-theory

Are there monotonically increasing uncomputable functions f that are bounded by computable functions?

$$ \exists f,g: f\ uncomputable\ \land f\ monotonically\ increasing\ \land\ g\ computable\ \land\ f \in O(g)  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Let $L$ be any undecidable language (e.g. the halting problem), w.l.o.g. encoded over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ and such that all $x \in L$ start with $1$. Further, let $\leq_\text{lex}$ denote the lexicographical order of strings over the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ and let $\operatorname{bin}(n)$ denote the binary representation of a natural number $n$.
Define
$$f_L(n) = |\{x \in L \mid x \leq_\text{lex} \operatorname{bin}(n) \}|$$
and observe that $f_L$ is monotonically increasing and satisfies $f_L(n) \leq n$ (and thus $f_L \in O(n)$).
Finally, note that $L$ can be decided using an oracle for $f_L$, and hence $f_L$ is not computable.